# is it possible to build and new a structure in a loop?

Tags: c#

I want to know that How can I walk through this loop ?
this has a root 
two chldren priv and nonpriv
and children of them for 
priv:0,1,2,...,1023
and children of Nonpriv:
1024,..,65535

```
              |Any______________PORT|
                 |              |
             |Priv|          |Non-Priv|
            |||||...||||   ||||....|||||
            0123,.....1023 1024,...65535
```

I mean that 0 is in a distinct Node
1 is in a distinct Node
2 is in a distinct Node
these ports has parent PRIV
my reason of distincting them is that maybe some day 0 will have the list of children
they could be in a list and we can have a list of nodes or they could be in a list of strings but I can not decide what to do next about the list of string
and the problem with list of Node is in the for loop which I couldn't build Nodes

Now I can't configure the for loop how should I correct my code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace IDS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Node root = new Node("Any_PORT");
            List<Node> portcat = new List<Node>();
            Node Priv = new Node("Priv");
            Node NonPriv=new Node("Non-Priv");
            root.setchildren(portcat);
            root.Thisisroot();
            root.setNodeinlist(Priv);
            root.setNodeinlist(NonPriv);
            Priv.setparent(root);
            NonPriv.setparent(root);
            List<Node> portsP = new List<Node>();
            Priv.setchildren(portsP);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
            {

            }
    //I tried this one but I can't fix between Nodes and list of a string        
    List<string> portsN = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 1024; i < 65535; i++)
            {
                portsN.Add(i.ToString());
            }
        }

        public class Node
        {
            public string Data;
            public List<Node> Children = new List<Node>();
            public Node parent;
            public Node(string r)
            {
                this.Data = r;
             }
            public Node Thisisroot()
            {
                this.parent = null;
                return this;
            }
            public void setchildren(List<Node> list)
            {
                this.Children = list;
            }
            public List<Node> getchildren()
            {
                return this.Children;
            }
            public void setparent(Node p)
            {
                this.parent = p;
            }
            public Node getparent()
            {
                return this.parent;
            }
            public void setNodeinlist(Node n)
            {
                this.Children.Add(n);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you want to use a `List<Node>` and add to that list. Also I'd encourage you to walk through a C# tutorial first before asking questions.

Comment: You need `List<Node>` rather than `List<string>`, see my answer.

Comment: @Negin Nicki: Is "error am I a stupid?!" the actual error message you received? If not, can you please post the actual error message? It's generally a lot easier to fix errors if you read them, and we can only do that if you post the actual message.

Comment: `List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>()` or what you mean by new it?

Comment: Nope it is not error! I tried Node i here and it shows me this error!:a local variable named i can not be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to i which is already used in a parent or current scope to denote something else

Comment: @sll  sorry I couldn't understand what you told me

Comment: You asked ` how can I new it in my code?`, I've answered = just do `List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>()`, or you mean add enw items in code? Then just `nodes.Add(new Node(..))`

Comment: @NeginNicki: The error message you posted is pretty clear (by the way, did you try to understand it before you copy and pasted it?). The problem is that you have used the same name to mean two different things! Even if you could do it, it would be *incredibly* confusing to give the same name to two different things in the same scope. Would you call your son the same name as yourself? Oh wait... some people *do* do that! Sigh...

Comment: @sll I have list that is children of my tree then I want to add data which are 0,..,1023 so I thought that I should build a node which has 0 data then build a node which has 1 data then 2 then 3,...till 1023 now these nodes are in this list would you please tell me how can I complete the for loop here if my approach is totally wrong then what should I do?

Comment: @MarkByers well if I define Node x it will be always Node x is it possible to new a Node and save it I think it will be crashed after another time that i will be plused

Comment: Ok let's clarify your final goal, you doing somethign with Nodes tree and ports, you want to build some tree-hierarchy with ports information, and looks like part of hierarchy should be of Node-type and part simple string representing port-number, also you are doing two loops one from 0-1024 and second one from 1024-65xxx, so colud you please EDIT yur question and draw basically hierarchy you are trying to build, with two-three nodes for example

Comment: @MarkByers I mean when I exit the loop it will have just the 1023 if I set the name to a constant variable like X

Comment: @sll ok I will edit it prompt Thanks yes you got my point

Comment: @MarkByers I was totally confused! here you were right I am so sorry ACCEPTED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a collection to hold your objects, such as a list:

```
List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
{
    nodes.Add(new Node(i.ToString()));    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `List<Node>` rather than `List<string>`.

LINQ for help:

```
IList<Node> nodes = Enumerable.Range(1024, 65535)
                              .Select(i => new Node(i.ToString))
                              .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your helps sorry That I got your time

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the variable name, it will hold the value of the last iteration and wont be visible outside the loop. You need to have a list of Node type objects and then in that list you could add instance of type node inside the loop

```
List<Node> nodeList = new List<Node>()

     for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
                {
                nodeList.Add(new Node(i.ToString()));    
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you mean to build a list manually like this:

```
Node first;
Node lastCreated = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
{
    Node n = new Node(i.ToString());
    if(i == 0)
        first = n;
    n.parent = lastCreated;
    lastCreated = n;
}
```

still you need to have another reference in each item like this:

```
class Node{
    public string Data;
    public Node parent;
    public Node child;
    public Node(string r)
    {
        this.Data = r;
     }
}
```

then

```
Node first;
Node lastCreated = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
{
    Node n = new Node(i.ToString());
    if(i == 0)
        first = n;
    n.Parent = lastCreated;
    if(lastCreated != null)
        lastCreated.child = n;
    lastCreated = n;
}
```